# iMessage on iPhone 5s iOS 9.0.2 : Delivered isn't showing up on sent messages

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

In my iMessages that I send to other iMessage users the "delivered" text is not showing up after I press send, but the people who I sent it to say they received it and are able to respond.

Also my iMessage is claiming that I have cellular data turned off, but I don't.

I've already tried restarting my phone and I've checked that the bill was paid (it was). I've also already followed all steps suggested by apple on their support site. Still nothing. Its frustrating and I'd like to know if something has actually delivered.

Does anyone have any clue what is happening and how I can fix it or is it simply a bug in the programming of IOS 9.0.2?

Comment: I am having the same problem on iOS 9.1 Public Betas 3 and 4.